# How to decode JSON object with any number of key–value pairs in Swift?

Tags: json, swift, codable, decodable

I’m using Swift to try and decode [JSON:API](https://jsonapi.org)-formatted JSON results. The JSON I’m trying to parse has a shape like this:

```json
{
    "data": {
        "type": "video",
        "id": "1",
        "attributes": {
            "name": "Test Video",
            "duration": 1234
        }
    }
}
```

I’m trying to create a Swift struct that will encode these JSON objects, but I’m having issues with the `attributes` key as it could contain any number of attributes.

The Swift structs I’m trying to encode the above into look like this:

```swift
struct JSONAPIMultipleResourceResponse: Decodable {
    var data: [JSONAPIResource]
}
```

```swift
struct JSONAPIResource: Decodable {
    var type: String
    var id: String
    var attributes: [String, String]?
}
```

The `type` and `id` attributes should be present in *every* JSON:API result. The `attributes` key should be a list of any number of key–value pairs; both the key and value should be strings.

I’m then trying to decode a JSON response from an API like this:

```swift
let response = try! JSONDecoder().decode(JSONAPIMultipleResourceResponse.self, from: data!)
```

The above works if I leave the `type` and `id` properties in my `JSONAPIResource` Swift struct, but as soon as I try and do anything with `attributes` I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Swift.DecodingError.valueNotFound(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "attributes", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "poster_path", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected String but found null value instead.", underlyingError: nil)): file /Users/[User]/Developer/[App]/LatestVideosQuery.swift, line 35  
2020-07-14 16:13:08.083721+0100 [App][57157:6135473] Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Swift.DecodingError.valueNotFound(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "attributes", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "poster_path", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected String but found null value instead.", underlyingError: nil)): file /Users/[User]/Developer/[App]/LatestVideosQuery.swift, line 35
```

I get Swift is very strongly typed, but I’m unsure on how to encode this unstructured data in Swift. My plan is to have generic `JSONAPIResource` representations of resources coming back from my API, then I can then map into model structs in my Swift application, i.e. convert the above JSON:API resources into a `Video` struct.

Also, I’m trying to naïvely convert values in the `attributes` object to strings but as you may see, `duration` is an *integer* value. If there’s a way to have `attributes` in my `JSONAPIResource` struct retain primitive values such as integers and booleans and not just strings, I’d be keen to read how!

Comment: "list of any number of key–value pairs". Do you know all possible values?

Comment: @LeoDabus Not up front, as the attributes change depending on the `type` of the resource. I essentially just want a “bag” of keys and values, if possible.

Comment: @MartinBean... what do you want the final model to be? "A bag of key/values" is a Dictionary, but as you saw, if you can't ensure that the value are of the same type, then you can't *just decode it*

Comment: The `attributes` dictionary is not `[String:String]` as the value for `duration` is `Int`. Look if there is a consistent dependency between the `type` value and the corresponding `attributes` dictionary. If there is one use an enum with associated types and a bunch of different structs.

Comment: @vadian I know. I noted that at the end of my post.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a completely generic bag of key/values (which might indicate a need for a possible design change), you can create an `enum` to hold the different (primitive) values that JSON can hold:

```
enum JSONValue: Decodable {
   case number(Double)
   case integer(Int)
   case string(String)
   case bool(Bool)
   case null

   init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
      let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()

      if let int = try? container.decode(Int.self) {
         self = .integer(int)
      } else if let double = try? container.decode(Double.self) {
         self = .number(double)
      } else if let string = try? container.decode(String.self) {
         self = .string(string)
      } else if let bool = try? container.decode(Bool.self) {
         self = .bool(bool)
      } else if container.decodeNil() {
         self = .null
      } else {
        // throw some DecodingError
      }
   }
}
```

and then you could set `attributes` to:

```
var attributes: [String: JSONValue]
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is a consistent relationship between the `type` value and the key-value pairs in `attributes` I recommend to declare `attributes` as enum with associated types and decode the type depending on the `type` value.

For example

```
let jsonString = """
{
    "data": {
        "type": "video",
        "id": "1",
        "attributes": {
            "name": "Test Video",
            "duration": 1234
        }
    }
}
"""

enum ResourceType : String, Decodable {
   case video
}

enum AttributeType {
    case video(Video)
}

struct Video : Decodable {
    let name : String
    let duration : Int
}

struct Root : Decodable {
    let data : Resource
}

struct Resource : Decodable {
    let type : ResourceType
    let id : String
    let attributes : AttributeType
    
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case type, id, attributes }
    
    init(from decoder : Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.type = try container.decode(ResourceType.self, forKey: .type)
        self.id = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
        switch self.type {
            case .video:
                let videoAttributes = try container.decode(Video.self, forKey: .attributes)
                attributes = .video(videoAttributes)
        }
    }
}

let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)

do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
    print(result)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```